# How to render two different arrays data into a single array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, ecmascript-6

In my react state, I have data coming in into two different arrays and I would like my component to `put both arrays data in a single array`. This is the data format that I have for both arrays:

```
data: {
  array1: [
    {
      name: "John Doe"
    },
    {
      name: "Bob Williams"
    }
  ]

  array2: [
    {
      name: "Clark Kent"
    },
    {
      name: "Bruce Wayne"
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I make my code return data so the end result looks like the defined below:

```
_.map(Object.values(this.state.data), (item,key) => {
  return _.map(item, (data) => {
    return {
      name: data.name
    }
  })
})
```

**Desired output:**

```
data: [
  { name: "John Doe" },
  { name: "Bob Williams" },
  { name: "Clark Kent" },
  { name: "Bruce Wayne" }
]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`Spread operator ...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to merge 2 arrays into one.

```js
const data = {array1:[{name:"John Doe"},{name:"Bob Williams"}],array2:[{name:"Clark Kent"},{name:"Bruce Wayne"}]};;

const result = {data: [...data.array1, ...data.array2]};
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks Nguyen for the response. This looks good. Will this also work if I have other properties inside both arrays and if I want to target the other properties to display the data on the page?

Comment: Yes, it is @Shaun

Answer (score 0):

Use [Array.prototype.flat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)

```
const data = Object.values(this.state.data).flat();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Object.values(this.state.data).reduce((p, c) => p.concat(c), []);
```